# Box-shadow does not work in IE on my web server

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I create a html file like this:

```
<style>
    td#emboss a{
        background:#F9F8F3;border:1px solid #D4D2D2;display:block;width:220px;
        text-decoration:none;line-height:30px;font-size:12px;color:black;padding-right:3px;text-align:center;
        border-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(150,150,150,.2),inset 2px 4px 10px rgba(150,150,150,.6);
    }
    td#emboss a:hover{
        color:#18314B;width:220px;display:block;
        font-weight: bold;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(10,10,10,.1),inset 2px 4px 10px rgba(10,10,10,.1);

    }
</style>
<table>

    <tr><td id="emboss"><a href='#'>My Link</a>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

When I show this in my system it is correct,but when I upload it on my web server in IE the 'box-shadow' does not work,how can I fix this problem?

Comment: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be related to the document mode.
The document mode can be changed from is default value (Edge) also via X-UA-compatible HTTP header and the document will be rendered in legacy mode...

here the link with more information on it
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255001(v=vs.85).aspx

and a link can help you to configurate the web server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj676913(v=vs.85).aspx